# Without performing the integral to show

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Without performing the integral, show that
$$
\int_{-2}^{2}e^{x^2}x^3dx=0
$$
Please help me. I do not know where to start.

Comment: Try graphing it, perhaps that will make it clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that the product of an even function and an odd function is an odd function and

$$
\int_{-a}^{a} f(x) \, dx = 0
$$

if $f(x)$ is odd. Hope this helps.

Comment: really helpful now i remember the even and odd functions to help integration

Answer (score 13):

Hint:  even and odd functions.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better as a comment? :)

Comment: @Shaun No, because it answers the question. :)

Comment: @Potato That's fair enough :)

Answer (score 0):

The curve of the function is symmetric on both sides of the y-axis as well as x-axis. Also, $f(-x)=-f(x)$. So, the area is $0$.